# Best color for outdoor(/indoor) table?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, maintenance

I'd like to know the best color for the surface of a table-tennis table?

In this case the table is coming for outdoor use (it's also played indoors during winter), where the natural white light may be bright, the grass and trees green, and so on. During winter the artificial light is much more yellow, and walls usually white.

What does experience tell about the color? Is the contrast to the white ball as good on a grey tabletop as on a blue tabletop for example?

I know the table should officially be blue/green in competitions, but can one notice a difference? Are they *really* better colours than eg grey when playing as a hobby?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not advised to play table tennis outdoors directly the sun as it will cause damage (warping)to the table's surface. A blue table is the best because it provides the best vision of the ball (White or yellow).